# Fast and smooth scrolling using google maps api possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, zooming

i am working on a react application in which we use google maps. The goal that we want to achieve is to make the map's scrolling as fast and as smooth as possible, and ideally as close to jslancerteam's vector map's scrolling,  which can be found here: https://jslancerteam.github.io/crystal-dashboard/#/maps/vector-map . By fast i mean skip some zoom levels per mousewheel scroll as can be seen on the vector map above.

I have tried many things i found online but the closest i got was by disabling the default scrollwheel option of the map and trying to make a custom function called on every mousewheel scroll captured by a listener.

I have tried two different approaches , one by adding an integer value z as increment to the zoom level of the map (i think we need a value between 2 and 3 levels for each scroll.). I wrote the second approach myself and the idea behind it is to give different multipliers to map's zoom level depending on the value of the current zoom level.( For example having faster zoomIn if you are at a low zoom level and slower if you are already pretty zoomed in. The opposite is true for the zoomOut.).

Although i think the second approach has some potential to become smooth, sadly i don't believe the google maps can achieve the same kind of smoothness and fast scrolling as in the vector maps example.

In google maps every layer(tiles) is going to be rendered (grey tiles) even if you try to increase the zoom level by a great value on every scroll because they are served on demand.
When scrolling the mousewheel gently , the results are close to what we would like. When scrolling the mousewheel very fast, the map tiles don't have time to get rendered

On the other hand, we believe that other libraries don't render said layers , and thus they get that smooth feeling.

Unfortunately the application is very dependent on the maps and has a lot of it's basic functionality built around them , so we would like to avoid migrating to another maps library if we are able to for now.

```
// Need to point out that in some other point in the app
// the scrollwheel map option is set to false and
// the max zoom level is set to 22 


//
//1st Approach
//

// Having disabled the default scrollwheel i wanted to 
// make the custom scroll follow the mouse 
// so i get the coordinates of the mouse through a listener
// and then i set it as the center of the map on every scroll

     maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function (event) {
                displayCoordinates(event.latLng);               
            });

  let displayCoordinates=function (pnt) {

            var lat = pnt.lat();
            lat = lat.toFixed(4);
            var lng = pnt.lng();
            lng = lng.toFixed(4);
            mouselatlng =new LatLng(lat,lng)
        }

// the listener used to capture the mousewheel scroll
maps.event.addDomListener(map.getDiv(), 'mousewheel', fx);

// the function called on every scroll
// depending if you zoomIn or zoomOut
// a z is added to the zoom level of the map to replicate
// the zoom functionality

let fx = function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              map.setCenter(mouselatlng); //setting the mouse coords as center


//
// increase by 3 levels on zoomIn : decrease by 3 (-3) on zoomOut
//
              var z = e.wheelDelta > 0 || e.detail < 0 ? 3 : -3;
              map.setZoom(Math.max(0, Math.min(22, map.getZoom() + z)));
              setTimeout(()=>{
                  map.setZoom(map.getZoom + z);
              },80)
              return false;
           };



//
//2nd Approach
//

maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function (event) {
                displayCoordinates(event.latLng);               
            });



let displayCoordinates=function (pnt) {

            var lat = pnt.lat();
            lat = lat.toFixed(4);
            var lng = pnt.lng();
            lng = lng.toFixed(4);
            mouselatlng =new LatLng(lat,lng)
        }



 maps.event.addDomListener(map.getDiv(), 'mousewheel', fx);

  let fx = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                map.setCenter(mouselatlng);


             // Using different multipliers for some zoom levels
             // the logic is not finished and the numbers used are not
             // final. This was a test to see if the multipliers could 
             // make a difference.

                if(map.getZoom >= 10){
                    var z = e.wheelDelta > 0 || e.detail < 0 ? 1.1 : 0.91;
                }
                else if ((map.getZoom >= 7)){
                    var z = e.wheelDelta > 0 || e.detail < 0 ? 1.2 : 0.7;
                }else{
                    var z = e.wheelDelta > 0 || e.detail < 0 ? 1.4 : 0.6;
                }

                map.setZoom(Math.max(0, Math.min(22, map.getZoom() * z)));
                return false;
            };
```

Comment: I'm sorry due to having low reputation i could not use any image files on the post. So here is an image of what happens when you try to scroll fast and the map don't have  time to be rendered properly https://imgur.com/z3BRVjk